# Norm of square root of a matrix: is it a constant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

Let $A$ be a symmetric positive semi-definite real matrix. Let now $B = \sqrt{A}$ in the sense that $BB^\top = A$. Now, $B$ is not unique (neither up to a multiplicative constant) if no particular structure is required (e.g., as in the Cholesky decomposition).

Let now $\|\cdot\|_p$ be the $p$-norm on matrices induced by the vectorial $L^p$ norm. Is it true that $\|B\|_p = \mathrm{const}$, where $B$ is a square root of $A$?

Comment: It is easy to see that it is not constant, for instance, in the case that $A = I$.

Comment: It will be constant, however, in the case that $p=2$ (but in no other cases)

Comment: @BenGrossmann fantastic